# How to declare typescript type as "variable" for repeated use?

Tags: typescript, union-types

I am learning typescript right now and from what I know you can do
(This is just a simplified example):

```js
interface IExample1 { 
  Value: String | Number | String[] | Number [] 
}

interface IExample2 { 
  Value: String | Number | String[] | Number [] 
}
```

Both `value`'s of `IExample1` and `IExample2` have the same types. Is there a way to somehow declare the type of `Value` and reuse it when needed?

Would look something like this:

```js
ValueType = String | Number | String[] | Number [] 

interface IExample1 { 
  Value: ValueType
}

interface IExample2 { 
  Value: ValueType
}
```

For some reason I was unable to find anything related (not sure what to search for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documenation:

> Type aliases create a new name for a type. Type aliases are sometimes similar to interfaces, but can name primitives, unions, tuples, and any other types that you’d otherwise have to write by hand.

```
type ValueType = String | Number | String[] | Number [] 

interface IExample1 { 
  Value: ValueType
}

interface IExample2 { 
  Value: ValueType
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QCrmgXigZWAJwEsA7AcygB8oA5JAWwCMJ9LcCTSBtAXVdseZQeUALAAocSWDMAZnADG0AJIBRAB5w6YBBACMUAN6ixUWIhQAuM8jQZxAX3GTi0-HMVRVGrToBMh41N4GytglHRIByA)

A new type is not created, just a new name for the type is created.

Answer (score 2):

Try following code

```
type valueType = String | Number | String[] | Number []

interface IExample1 { 
  Value: valueType
}

interface IExample2 { 
  Value: valueType
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'd willing to bet that for this simple case you don't need to use constructor types like `Number` or `String`. You should use `stirng` and `number` instead. Please see [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#about-number-string-boolean-symbol-and-object)

`Number` type refers to `Number` constructor in pure js, whereas `number` refers to primitive type.

If you want to avoid repetition, you can use [distributive-conditional-types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```js
type ValueType<T> = T extends any ? T | T[] : never

type Value = ValueType<string | number>

interface IExample1 {
    Value: Value
}

interface IExample2 {
    Value: Value
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QCrggHlQPigXilSggA9gIA7AEwGco5KQoB%20IqAHyIG0BdKAFxRKEAG4QATgCgpoSLEQoCC5GgyZawCQEtKAc07CkAWwBGknDN0UJAMzgBjaAEkAoqTjGwCCAEYoAN5SUCEqKELwqlIAvlaUNvZOUG4eXj4ATIHBoZHhYRAxQA)